# Multi-entry, multi-exit co-routine in Python

Tags: python, coroutine

```
def print2Combs(n):
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            print (i,j)

print2Combs(5)
```

That code gives me this output:

```
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
```

Supposedly, this function is a co routine and it is a multi entry, multi exit function. And it is a generator. I failed to see the connections and can't answer followings.

1. Why it is a multi entry function?
2. Why it is a multi exit function?
3. Why it is a co routine?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A generator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html) is a function that returns an iterator.

`print2Combs` returns None. None is not an iterator, so `print2Combs` is not a generator.

[A coroutine is a kind of `generator`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) which allows values or exceptions to be passed in when execution resumes.

Since `print2Combs` is not a generator, it can not be a coroutine.

Comment: Thank you. Why didn't the lifeguard save the hippie?

Comment: Because the ocean was multi-entry but single-exit? :)